# Marker selection based on the button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, leaflet

I have two markers & two button. By default if no button is clicked or button A is clicked and when user drag the slider a circle is drawn around the marker. And when user click second button, the slider must make circle in second marker. I have tried this code but I am not sure how to set the circle set to second marker.

```js
let myloc = new L.LatLng(13.7433242, 100.5421583);
let myloc1 = new L.LatLng(14.979900, 102.097771);
let map = L.map('map').setView(myloc, 8);

const scale = ' meter';

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.streets',
  accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2FuaW5kcmEiLCJhIjoiY2pqam5qZzZnMHRycTNrbWR3ZGF4Mmd5eSJ9.ZRIVhopMmACa80OQ0yZN3g'
}).addTo(map);

let marker = L.marker(myloc).addTo(map);
L.marker(myloc1).addTo(map);

$(function() {
  var slider = document.getElementById('myRange');
  var output = document.getElementById('demo');
  output.innerHTML = slider.value + scale;

  slider.oninput = function(val) {
    output.innerHTML = this.value + scale;
    circle.setRadius(this.value);
  }

  $('.btn-a').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() == 'First') {
      myloc = myloc;

    } else if ($(this).val() = 'Second') {
      myloc = myloc1;
    }
  });

  let circle = L.circle(myloc, {
    color: '#ff0000',
    weight: 0.1,
    fillColor: '#ff0000',
    radius: 0
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="map"></div>

    <div class="scope">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="15000" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
      <p>Radius:
        <span id="demo"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="button" id="btn-first" class="btn-a" value="First">
    <input type="button" id="btn-second" class="btn-a" value="Second">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any circle in the map.!

Comment: @weBBer did you try slider below the map?

Comment: You're almost there, you need to remove and re-add the circle layer after updating `myloc`.

Comment: @peeebeee for now I solve by adding a global var circle; then  circle = L.circle(myloc, {
....
    }).addTo(map);
    $('.btn-a').on('click', function(e){
        if ($(this).val() == 'First') {
            circle = L.circle(myloc, {
               ....
            }).addTo(map);

        } else if($(this).val() == 'Second') {
            circle = L.circle(myloc1, {
                ....
            }).addTo(map);
        }
    });
This is the worst type but it was urgent for me.. can you help me

Comment: That's not a bad solution. You don't have to re-use the same variable, you could use a local variable in the function and initialise it and `.addTo` the map each time. Not sure that's really any better.